# Touchpad start working with delay

Tags: drivers, touchpad, laptop, asus, 17.10

I'm using ubuntu 17.10 on an Asus zenbook ux430.
I'm having some problem with the touchpad.
On startup, or more generally after i login, the tuchpad won't work for about 5/10 seconds.
After that delay, it start working normaly.

(I just notice, that if i wait in to the login screen, without typing the password, after 5/10 seconds tuchpad start working, and keep working after logging in)